# UIWebView and click link

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I know that most likely the answer is very obvious, but I've looked everywhere on the internet and I have not found anything. I use this method to see if the user presses on the WebView

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType; {
```

I can assure you that it works.

What I want to do is to make different actions according to the id

es

```
<a id="hello" href="..."><img src="..." /></a>
```

once the delegate detect "touch click" on the img with the "hello" id, I would do some custom stuff, like `[self callSomething];`

Could you show me how to do it using a sample code? thanks

Comment: why u r using webview then? use uibutton and set background image and onclick of button call [self callsomething]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your  code as follows

```
  <a id="hello" href='didTap://image><img src="..." /></a>
```

and in the delegate method try like this.

```
 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
 {     
NSString *absoluteUrl = [[request URL] absoluteString];
 NSString*temp=[absoluteUrl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"@" withString:@""];

if ([temp isEqualToString:@"didTap://image"])
{
    [self your method];
}
return YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`UIWebView` can't receive id from dom element but one thing you can do is pass value in `href` url with a parameter `hello` like:

```
<a id="hello" href="//myurl?id=hello"><img src="..." /></a>
```

and you can get parameter as:

```
URLParser *parameter = [[URLParser alloc] initWithURLString:@"http://myurl/id=hello"];
NSString *id = [parameter valueForVariable:@"id"];
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you should put javascript onClick handler to any DOM element you need

f.e

```
<a onClick="callNativeSelector('doSomething');" ... > </a>

javascript function callNativeSelector(nativeSelector) { // put native selector as param
    window.location = "customAction://"+nativeSelector;
}
```

On UIWebView delegate's method ignore links like above

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{

  if ([[request.URL scheme] isEqualToString:@"customAction"]) {
        //Fetching image URL
        NSLog(@"Custom selector is %@", [request.URL host])
        ...
        // Always return NO not to allow `UIWebView` process such links
        return NO; 
    }
    ....
}
```

There are benefits from my point of view:

- Not associated with specific DOM element like `<a href=...>`, you can assign such handler to anything you need
- Not associated with html `id` attribute
- Ability inside `UIWebView` ignore loading such links and just execute your customSelector nativly