# OnClick UIWebview

Tags: javascript, html, ios, uiwebview

I'm loading html file from local. I'm using `UIWebView` for display html page. In html page i have some image. When i click the image i need to go `UIViewController` page. Prevoiusly i used button type form submitted. But now i don't want use button type form submitted.

.btn{margin:15px auto 15px;width:293px; height:55px; border:none;  cursor:pointer; display:block;}

viewcontroller:

```
 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSString *absoluteUrl = [[request URL] absoluteString];
    NSString*temp=[absoluteUrl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"@" withString:@""];

    if ([temp isEqualToString:@"didTap://image"])
    {

        [QCARHelper startDetection];
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];


    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: are you sure that javascript executes redirect: window.location="didTap://image" ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are owner of `HTML` code, you can simply manage redirects on javascript and catch all of them in `UIWebView` delegate.

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18464283/uiwebview-and-click-link/18465001#18465001) for more deatils

Comment: I changed my code..It's not working..check updated code

Comment: when click the link it going to viewcontroller. Then come back goes to html pages again click the button, it's not loading. Is it causing because of local html other pages links?

Comment: Not sure if I understand. Are you getting those "lading" pages in UIWebView?